# HTML5 clicable canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am creating a circle on my canvas. Is it possible to make my circle clickable?

```
function createCircle(context, x, y, radius, color) {
   context.beginPath();
   context.fillStyle = color;
   context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
   context.closePath();
   context.fill();
}
```

Comment: If the primary purpose of your use of canvas is to create clickable objects consider using SVG instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. If you want to change the cursor to the hand (the way it does on links), you can do that too. Simply add an onmousemove event to your canvas, and if the mouse's distance from the center (you may have to use Pythagoras) is less than the radius, change the canvas's CSS property of cursor to pointer. Else, of course, return the CSS property to default.
Similarly, add an onclick event, and detect when it is being clicked, and do your stuff when it's true.
You therefore have a clickable circle in your canvas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, between I did it alernatively, I put circular image and made it clicable, yes your suggestion is good and I can try my hands on it. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but i think you should capture the `click` event on the `canvas` and then write a `function` which check if the clicked point is inside the circle radius. (ie the difference between the clicked point and the circle origin is less than or equal to the radius).

Comment: Turns out, you can use the canvas itself to figure out [whether a point is within a path](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath)

Comment: Really? I just copied that code to an HTML file, and it didn't work for me on Chrome. Which browsers support the method, @ellisbben?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to point out the function, not the example code.  The 'example' code they give is straight up broken and though it can be made to work (http://jsfiddle.net/Hk5d6/3/) I wouldn't use it as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

you can add **mousedown** event to your canvas or simply can add event listener as

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) 
{
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
        //Here ur getting mouse position x and y coordinates. 
  },
 false);
```